# How to use mainloop (from tinter) in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I was asking myself how I should use mainloop() from tkinter. I am writing a program to draw a affine function. I did a class Graph and 2 input functions + 2 drawing functions. My program is organized like this :

```
Class Graph:
    def __init__():
        #I init some variables
    def input_function():
        #I input the function
    def input_dimensions():
        #I input the dimensions
    def draw_grid():
        #I draw the x and y axis with graduation
        #Should I put a mainloop() here ?
    def draw_function():
        #I draw the function
        #Should I put a mainloop()here ?
    def main():
        Graph.input_function():
        Graph.input_dimensions():
        Graph.draw_grid():
        Graph.draw_function():
        #Should I put a mainloop() here ?

Graph.main():
#Should I put a mainloop() here ?
```

I would also like to know if there is a way to update the window after a mainloop so I could input another function

Comment: Just my opinion, but I think you need to learn Python better first. The class you've defined as many basic errors that have nothing to do with tkinter. The latter is fairly complex and poorly documented, so you really ought to have more advanced skills than you do before tackling it.

Comment: I need to have a goal to work towards to learn so I choose this one, I know it is quite a challenge but thanks to platforms like Stackoverflow help a lot in such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @martineau mentioned, you should first organize your code. Here is what you can do:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #I init some variables
        self.master = master

    def input_function(self):
        #I input the function
    def input_dimensions(self):
        #I input the dimensions
    def draw_grid(self):
        #I draw the x and y axis with graduation
        #Should I put a mainloop() here ?
    def draw_function(self):
        #I draw the function
        #Should I put a mainloop()here ?
    def main(self):
        self.input_function()
        self.input_dimensions()
        self.draw_grid()
        self.draw_function()
        #Should I put a mainloop() here ?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    graph_class_object = Graph(master=root)
    graph_class_object.main()
    root.mainloop()
```

So what does it do? It creates a `Tk` object which is then passed to the class `Graph`. As you see, I passed the `Tk` object as the variable `master`. So you can use `self.master` as the parent of any new tkinter widgets like `Button`, `Label` etc. Like this:

```
    self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Button", height=1, width=20)
    self.button.pack(side="top", padx=50, pady=5)
```

The button initializing code should also be in your `init` function

Comment: Thanks so much for your help !

Comment: @Jonathcraft If it is working for you, could you please accept my answer? Thanks

Comment: Did it, what does __name__ == "__main__" mean ? Because I don't have anything called __name__  nor "__main__""

Comment: it's a python build-in function.

Comment: Sorry to ask you once more but I still have a problem. The window successfully launches but then launches infinitely. I copied the same code you wrote (I changed the name of the object and so on) and I initialized my only widget (a canvas) in __init__(self, master). I can show ou the complete code I wrote if you need.

Comment: @Jonathcraft It's probably best to ask another question, it will be clearer for everyone and is more in line with SO's policy of "One question, one answer".

Comment: @EthanField is right. If you can ask another question, it would be much more easier to understand your qustion. But I didn't get what you mean by launches infinitely. Do you want to close the tkinter UI by code ? In any case, please ask another question.